# Time measurement of pattern matching functions not working properly

Tags: c++, pattern-matching, buffer

For some reason all the times calculated are the same as from the first function that got iterated.

```
 for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
     ofstream os1("alphabet_1.txt"); // I am overwriting existing file
     os1<<txt;  // txt is randomly generated string from other function
     file_1 = fopen("alphabet_1.txt", "a+");

    StartCounter();
    while (!feof(file_1)) //reading file with buffer
    {
        const size_t nchars = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer)-1, file_1);
        buffer[nchars] = '\0';
        if (int i=0) BM(buffer, pat);
        if (int i=1) KMP(buffer, pat_a);
        if (int i=2) SUNDAY(buffer, pat_a);

    }
    time[i]=GetCounter();
    cout<<time[i]<<endl;
}
```

If I calculate the times separately it's 5 for BM, 9 for KMP and 8 for SUNDAY.

So my output from code above is something like:

```
5.42
5.30
5.28
```

If I change it like this:

```
        if (int i=1) BM(buffer, pat);
        if (int i=0) KMP(buffer, pat_a);
        if (int i=2) SUNDAY(buffer, pat_a);
```

output will be:

```
8.41
8.54
8.63
```

(So now all values are around KMP speed.)

I'm doing it this way because I want them to work on the same character string, otherwise I'd have to create 3 file_ and copy the string into each of them.

Example of wanted output:

```
5.34
9.43
8.22
```

Comment: why dont you first fix what was wrong in the code already here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56445053/while-loop-untill-end-of-file-not-working-properly ? You still have the same problem in your code

Comment: ...then, currently nobody but you can know where those times are coming from. If those function read and write stuff into the buffer, it is just to be expected that the times depend on the order in which you call them. Please read about [mcve]

Comment: That problem is already fixed, it just didn't work on buffer lower then 10.

Comment: not sure what you mean with "lower then 10". `while (!feof(file_1))` is the problem and it is still there

Comment: I got output that I wanted, I mean it read characters in buffer and seperated them with endline, it matched with txt file. Should I still remove it?

Comment: `if (int i=0)` is the same as `if (0)`. You meant `if (i == 0)`.

Comment: @molbdnilo That was it... funny how my brain decided to overlook it every time I read it line by line looking for error.

Comment: sorry, I can be stubborn, often it helps to find the problem, and sometimes I am too focused on the irrelevant to see the obvious. nice that you found it, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

molbdnilo:

> if (int i=0) is the same as if (0). You meant if (i == 0).

fire cloud:

> @molbdnilo That was it...